# Change picture using C# ONLY

Tags: c#, wpf

Goal:
Change the picture from picEnlarger into picXmark if there are any input data in the textbox txtSearch.

If no data input in the textbox then the picture picEnlarger should be displayed and picXmark should be hidden.

Problem:
I know how to do it in xaml but not in c# code.

I want to change the picture from/to visibility or hidden by using C# ONLY.

Please remember that I want to use less xaml code.

I also tried making the picture to be hidden/visible in the textbox txtSearch's event method ( private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)) with this code:

```
picXmark.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
picEnlarger.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

Unfortunately, I retrieve this message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

```xml
<TextBox Name="txtSearch" Width="143.243" TextChanged="txtSearch_TextChanged" Text="Search article" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="txtSearch_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
    <Image x:Name="picEnlarger" Height="14" Width="14" Source="/MediaStore;component/Bilder/search_enlarger2.gif" />
    <Image x:Name="picXmark" Height="8" Width="8" Source="/MediaStore;component/Bilder/search_xmark.gif" />
</TextBox>
```

Comment: i guess you are trying to change the visibility before these objects are drawn on the WPF window...

Comment: Your XAML ain't making any sense to me - it is not even valid.

Comment: Using less XAML normally means *a lot* more code-behind, why would you want that?

Comment: H.B. = To enable to make use the sourcecode to be more flexible when Im using more component in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TextChanged` event will work fine, the problem is that it's being raised before all your controls are initialized.

Try something like this

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (picEnlarger != null && picXmark != null)
    {
        if (txtSearch.Text == "")
        {
            picXmark.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            picEnlarger.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; 
        }
        else
        {
            picXmark.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            picEnlarger.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the `Images` before the `Textbox` like this

```xml
<Image x:Name="picEnlarger" Height="14" Width="14" Source="/MediaStore;component/Bilder/search_enlarger2.gif" />
<Image x:Name="picXmark" Height="8" Width="8" Source="/MediaStore;component/Bilder/search_xmark.gif" />
<TextBox Name="txtSearch" Width="143.243" TextChanged="txtSearch_TextChanged" Text="Search article" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="txtSearch_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
```

Comment: Not a very robust solution. If you deside to move some controls around in xaml, the program might start crashing again

Comment: The pictures needs to be inside of textbox.